# Problem understanding how a non-static method is called

Tags: java, libreoffice

I'm reading the Java code of libreoffice and there's one thing I don't really understand.
The method [updateUI()](http://opengrok.libreoffice.org/xref/components/wizards/com/sun/star/wizards/fax/FaxWizardDialogImpl.java#371)   calls 2 time the method [updateUI](http://opengrok.libreoffice.org/xref/components/wizards/com/sun/star/wizards/ui/event/DataAware.java#140)  and they pass as a parameter a Vector variable, BUT this method doesn't accept any parameter. Anybody can explain me what this parameter does ? if updateUI() is called this way:

```
UnoDataAware.updateUI();
```

it complains and says:

> non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 1):

There is another method in the second link you provided: (line 203)

```
 public static void updateUI(Collection dataAwares) {
            for (Iterator i = dataAwares.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
                ((DataAware) i.next()).updateUI();
         }
```

This is method that is being called 2 times. Static means you have to specify the Class name before you can call it. Unless you are apart of that class.

Users.getFirstName() (example)

Comment: Static doesn't mean you have to specify the class name before you can call it, it just means that you *can* specify the class name. You can do `someInstance.someStaticMethod();`. However, within a "static context" (i.e., the body of a static method), you cannot reference instance members. I.e., you cannot do `static void someMethod() { someNonStaticMethod(); }`. This is because there is no instance specified to call `someNonStaticMethod` on.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the Cross-Reference thingy is bad. Here's the method you are looking for:

[`DataAware.updateUI(Collection dataAwares)`](http://opengrok.libreoffice.org/xref/components/wizards/com/sun/star/wizards/ui/event/DataAware.java#198)

Answer (score 1):

When you call the static version of this method you are not using it within the context of an instantiated object. This is the reason you need to pass a parameter to the static method so that it knows which objects to update the UI for.

That parameter will allow the static `updateUI` method to iterate through a collection of DataAware objects and call *their* `updateUI` method from a non-static context. That means that the no-parameter `updateUI` doesn't need a reference to the object because it belongs to an object.

Answer (score 0):

`updateUI()` is an instance method, so you have to call it from an instance, while `updateUI(Collection dataAwares)` is a static method, and is called directly from the class.

And from the same source:

> ```
>          /**
> 199      * given a collection containing DataAware objects,
> 200      * calls updateUI() on each memebr of the collection.
> 201      * @param dataAwares a collection containing DataAware
> ```
>
> objects.
>       202      */

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the wrong line.

Look at line [203](http://opengrok.libreoffice.org/xref/components/wizards/com/sun/star/wizards/ui/event/DataAware.java#203) ,that's the method being called.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function which is called:

`public static void updateUI(Collection dataAwares)`

not

`public void updateUI()`